# Amazon music not recognizing uploaded albums

Tags: music, amazon-music

I have subscribe to the [Amazon Music](https://www.amazon.com/musiclibrary) service and have uploaded large portions of my library.  But some of the albums do not show up properly.

For example I have a copy of the [O Brother, Where Art Thou?](http://amzn.com/B00004XQ83) sound track, that I originally purchased as a CD, ripped in iTunes and uploaded using the [documented procedure](http://www.amazon.com/gp/help/customer/display.html?nodeId=201379280).  When I search for the album though in the iOS, or PC Amazon music app the sound it appears as if I have lots of 'O Brother, Where Art Thou?' albums with single songs.

I assume that amazon uses some attributes of the songs to create the groupings, what attributes do I need to fix to make the album show up properly?  The same album shows up as an album properly within iTunes.

[image: broken album]

Comment: This happened to me in iTunes and I fixed it by clicking the “part of a compilation” option.

Comment: Which I had already done in iTunes for this album before uploading to Amazon.